Vertically align FontAwesome icons of different sizes in unordered list
We are using Bootstrap v4.6.2 and FontAwesome 5.15.4. We have the following HTML code snippet which renders an unordered list with differently-sized FontAwesome icons (0.8em vs 0.44em).


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li>
    <i class="fa-li fa fa-star fa-sm" style="font-size: 0.8em;"></i>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fa-li fas fa-circle fa-sm" style="font-size: 0.44em;"></i>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>



Icons in front of the links are not aligned vertically. Circle icon is much more to the right than the star icon. Icons should also be horizontally aligned with text (currently, circle icon is much higher than it should be). How can we achieve the required alignments?

Frankly, I don't think you can without a lot of fiddling. The icons don't have the same font-size and are absolutely positioned. My suggestion would be to have them the same font-size and scale: .5 the bullet point

The fa-li class currently applies an value in em for left and width - overwriting those with rem values would probably be a good start, if you want those to be equal despite different font sizes.

It's probably worth pointing out that fa-sm already sets the font-size so you should probably remove that if you aren't going to use it.

Use flex-box with width to align icons to center vertically & horizontally. Simple.

Rather than alter the font-size, I suggest you use a transform (in this case scale ) as this will not affect layout.


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li>
    <i class="fa-li fa fa-star fa-sm" style="scale: 0.8"></i>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fa-li fas fa-circle fa-sm" style="scale: 0.44;"></i>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>



